# Floating action button onClick after hide/show

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I am having some trouble with FloatingActionButton from google's support design library. The button and the onClickListener work fine, but the problem is here:

when I hide the button and I show it afterwards, the button does not directly execute the onClick method when clicked the first time, it has to be clicked 2 times to work. I am not doing anything complicated in the onClick that could take time to run only a simple `setVisibility()` for a view. here is my code even though I doubt something is wrong there :

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         View searchL = findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);
         searchL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
 });
```

and the fab tag in the xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/fab" 
   android:layout_width="56dp"
   android:layout_height="56dp" 
   android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" 
   android:theme="@style/fabTheme" 
   android:layout_margin="15dp" 
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

**EDIT :** I removed the `OnCLickListener` and apparently the FloatingActionButton already has a clickListener set to it because when I click the action button it does a ripple effect. What is happening ? this is the only code in my activity. using an OnTouchListener instead of a click listener seems to solve the problem but it does not explain what is happening

---

Comment: it's hard to understand from the code here, it seems fine.
please upload the entire code, or at least tell where you set your on click.
also, please provide the code where you hide your fab.

Comment: Well thats the thing , I am not doing anything else special , I even created an empty activity to test this and a whole different app just to debug this problem , I think its a bug in the support library , the `onClickListener` is being set in the `onCreate` method and the I use `fab.hide()` and `fab.show()` to hide and show the button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `hide()` and `show()` methods that are used for floating action button animation, use `fab.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: well I would like to use .shide() and .show() to not have to handle animation

Answer (score 0):

good News answer is here:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```